How to disable automatic power saving mode?
In developer mode, my phone automatically switches to power saving mode when the battery level is below 75%. I would like to disable this feature.
In my previous Google Pixel 8 Pro phone, there was an option in the developer settings. However, on my new Honor X9b, I cannot find this option.
Is it possible to disable the automatic power saving mode through adb or another method?

Based on a discussion in comments we found out the problem and how to solve it:
Your problem is that on an old Android phone with a weak battery you have set-up a limit of 75% to start energy saving mode. This settings was synced via Google Cloud to your new phone and on the new phone there is no UI for changing the energy saver limit back to a more reasonable limit.
What you can do is check the system settings for a the 75% value:
In an adb shell execute:
settings list system 
settings list secure 
settings list global

For each command check the output if there is an setting with value 75 and a name that indicates something with energy or power.
In your case the matching setting value was low_power_trigger_level from settings global namespace.
This setting can be changed to 25% by the command
adb shell settings put global low_power_trigger_level 25

